# Get certificates from User pc in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, certificate, x509, digital-certificate

I have an C# ASP.NET application where the user will accept/reject some offers, which include storing his decision into the database, but what I need to do is to require him to select a digital certificate from his PC as a digital signature in order to accept/reject the offer and store the certificate's informations along with the other fields.

I was trying some x509 methods to load the certificates info's into a dropdownlist so the user could select the desired certificate, but I can't get it right.

Does anybody know how can I achieve that?

Comment: You can't. You can authenticate user by configuring HTTPS to require client cert, but you can't digitally sign info server side (As you need private key)

Comment: Do you have any suggestions about what can I do here?

Comment: You can write some ActiveX control that would perform data signing on client side and send signed data back to server.

Comment: Is there any way to require this certificate when the user is accessing the page?